# Should I use partial or show.html.erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, partial

I'm writing a web app containing posts and comments. Since there are many places I need to display a bunch of posts with their comments, I'm thinking about reusing the code. But I'm not sure if it is correct to use a partial `_posts.html.erb` that displays each post in `@posts`, or implement it directly through the show action in posts controller, and render this action when necessary in other views. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case, partials are your best bet.

As you said, *there are many places I need to display a bunch of posts with their comments*. A main premise of Rails is **Don't Repeat Yourself**. It is far more tidy (and programmatically sound) to retrieve `@posts` in your various controller actions *and then* render those posts/comments using partials in your views. Otherwise, you'd be rendering the `show` action within other views – views aren't really meant to render out actions, but the other way around, rather.

Comment: Partial is good practice for code clean, It will make your code DRY. Looks it suite your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, according to **DRY** principle your are thinking in a perfect manner, you should create a partial.

A good practice is instead of using `@posts`, you should pass posts as a locals like:

```
<%= render 'posts', posts: @posts %>
```

in this way you can use this partial from anywhere with providing just posts as locals without any dependency on `@posts` instance variable.